# How to set PHP environment variables on Ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, environment-variables

I'm sure this is easy if you know how, but I don't.

I've got an ubuntu 10.04 server running PHP5 under apache, all defaults and stuff.  The PHP needs some environment variables set.  How do I do it?

Do I put them in the apache site config?  Do I set them for the `nobody` user?  (Who doesn't have a .profile)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical place to set environment variables for apache in ubuntu is `/etc/apache2/envvars`.  Note that apache would run as the www-data user, not the nobody user.  www-data wouldn't have dotfiles in its home anyway.

Additionally, to make the variable available to php, I believe you will need to use [PassEnv](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#PassEnv) in the apache configuration

Comment: Looks like it should be right, but <? echo $_ENV['VAR_SET_IN_ENVVARS'] ?> isn't working.  :(

Comment: you php script is running via mod_php? or as a cgi?

Comment: it's running through mod_php... i'm pretty sure.  it's not in a cgi-bin dir, and a2enmod php was required.

Comment: Did you restart Apache so that envars would be reloaded?

Comment: @zoredache yes. :)

Comment: You can also check this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079237/ubuntu-how-php-can-read-environment-variable